# QTP Test controled in C# ( return Type Error)

Tags: c#, qtp

i am facing a problem about a return argument whose has an invalid type.

My goal is to retrieve all my objects of any QTP action ( combobox, text area, etc ) for testing them in Visual Studio.

For that i used the library  " QTObjectModelLib" for open/running QTP test, getting result,  in C#

For retrieve all my objects, i found in the QTP install directory, this dll "REPOSITORYUTILLib".

this air to operate,

i create my object

`private ObjectRepositoryUtilClass testss = new ObjectRepositoryUtilClass();`

And when i test this :

```
 testss.Load(@"D:\RepoTest.tsr");

 TOCollection collection =  testss.GetAllObjects();
```

or this :

```
testss.Load(@"D:\RepoTest.tsr");

 TOCollection collection =  testss.GetAllObjects("SwfWindow('Continent')");
```

I am facing this exception :

> " System.InvalidCastException : Return argument has an invalid type. "

I also tried to load my repository by action :

```
 "testss.LoadActionRepository(constanteRef.QTPTestPath, action.name);

  TOCollection collection =  testss.GetAllObjects(); "
```

Same issue...

Does any body have a solution :) ?

Thanks a lot.

Cyril.

Comment: Take a look at the thread at http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=438836&page=0

Comment: I wonder how questions like these get closed, ever. They are okay, but answered without an answer.

Comment: As http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144740/what-if-my-question-was-solved-in-comments-without-an-answer suggests, I´ll add an answer.

Comment: Sorry i used stackoverFlow for the first time ;)

Comment: No reason for sorrying, you did not do anything wrong. Just look at other newbies' questions here: "Sho me zeh codez", "It doez not worg", "Kindly deliver me the solution as soon as possible I kno u no hoh too it go" and so on and so on. I am sick of that, but not of questions that show a certain effort, and contain useful info.

Comment: :), i agree with you, but unfortunately this problem is everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=438836&page=0:

> Unfortunately, Mercury made extensive use of Variant types in their
>   COM interfaces, and that's something that Interop seems to choke on a
>   lot.

This, and other non-obvious facts, lead to the type cast problems you experience.

The key idea is to call the QTP routines via reflection, a la for example`testObject.GetType().InvokeMember()`, see the thread link for details.

Also, if you have an active support agreement: there used to be a KB article, http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM916723 ...the ID might lead to a fresher version.

Comment: Thanks for answered my question ;), i saw that InvokeMember() is not optimal.. But now i'm no longer blocked.  Today my goal is to enter the values ​​entered in the records to make unit testing;)

Comment: @berzek using reflection can be a pain in the arse but if you're using C# 4 you can use `dynamic` which simplifies things massively.

Comment: ok, thanks, i ll try it.  @Motti , is it possible to access input value during testing my application from C# ?  ( should i make an other thread for this question? ^^ ). Thanks

Comment: @berzek you should ask a seperate question, AFAIK input parameters are supported in QTP's automation.