# QTP Test controled in C#, Getting value from QTP DataTable

Tags: c#, qtp

According to this thread : [QTP Test controled in C# ( return Type Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420439/qtp-test-controled-in-c-sharp-return-type-error)

I'm facing an other problem,

I'm using QTP 11.0 and i control it with C# code. I'm able to retrieve all my object by name.

Now, My goal is to test input values ( from an excel sheet load into QTP ressources table ) which are used during my different record.

Test are easy to write but connect my C# code with QTP vb script is harder..

In my QTObjectModelLib library i can return a Dynamic Datatable :

```
dynamic dataTable = qtpApp.Test.LastRunResults.DataTable
```

But what i am supposed to be with this type of object?

I dont know if its possible but the best way to solve my problem should be an API who return me in real time my input values... Just a dream if i understood... ^^

QTP make me bow to the brain :).

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean by "QTP resources table"? The LastRunResults property you are referring to is a property of a run result. I guess you are looking for the datatable sheets that QTP supports to parameterize values used in the test. In QTP code, DataTable.GlobalSheet.Value ("Hi") returns  the value of the current test iteration's row in the Global data sheet, column "Hi". Do you want to access that? Then use the DataTable object, which is well documented in the documentation, as is LastRunResults. In your case,  qtpApp.Test.DataTable might be what you are looking for.

Comment: hey, thanks for answer again ;), "QTP resources tables" are tha table on QTP's GUI ( Global sheet, action 1 sheet, ...).  So you are right ;). i ever parameterize values in my Test file and i want to access to these values when they are input on the GUI i m testing. Normally i have tested qtpApp.Test.DataTable ( return a dynamic object). i ll look tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Both " qtpApp.Test.LastRunResults.DataTable " and " qtpApp.Test.DataTable"  return me a dataBase empty when i parse it to a dataBase object.

Comment: What to you mean by "dataBase" object? I think you mean DataTable? Does qtpApp.Test.DataTable return null, or what? It should be what QTP calls the DataTable object, with DataTable.getSheet (indexOrName) returning a DTSheet object that represents one sheet of data.